# LibGdx: Net.HttpResponse not "immutable" -is it reused or what?

Tags: libgdx, httprequest, httpresponse, mutable

In libgdx, When I use **Gdx.net.sendHttpRequest** with a **Net.HttpResponseListener** is the **Net.HttpResponse** object only valid to read from from within the **handleHttpResponse(Net.HttpResponse httpResponse)** method?

I tried:

```
String r=httpResponse.getResultAsString();
```

from within **handleHttpResponse(Net.HttpResponse httpResponse)**
and then again from outside somewhere, else. The object was there, but

```
String r=httpResponse.getResultAsString();
```

resulted in **""** this time. Is the Net.HttpResponse object reused internally or why would the result change? So I now the object is mutable, but still...it would be practical to pass it around to other places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's a stream; reading it once depleats it.  look at the implementation.  e.g. https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/net/NetJavaImpl.java#L72

Comment: Actually, it still doesn't work even if I only use getResultAsString() once!